# Find RaphaelJS elements by id, parent, or node type?

Tags: javascript, jquery, raphael

I am trying to find RaphaelJS elements by their ID or parent, but so far I haven't been able to. I want to use the built-in Raphael functions, such as `toFront()`.

So far, this is what I do:

```
super_set = [/*ALL SETS FROM http://readysetraphael.com/*/];
super_set.forEach(function(element) {
    element.forEach(function(state) {
        //Make all the Norway children red (children being all small islands and Norway itself)
        if(state.node.getAttribute("parent") === "Norway) {
            state.node.setAttribute("fill", "#FF0000");
        }

        //Set all text elements at the front, so we can read them
        if(state.node.tagName === "text") {
            state.toFront();
        }
    });
});
```

I realise this is really, really bad. What's even more bad, I run this a couple of times per second. I haven't noticed any lag at all, but it's really not ideal. What I basically want to achieve is the above, except it being outside the loops, with either jQuery or just plain JavaScript. Something like this:

```
$("[parent='Norway']").attr("fill", "red");
$("text").toFront();
```

Is something like this possible?

EDIT: Now that I come to think of it, `$("[parent='Norway']").attr("fill", "red");` works fine. It's the `toFront()` part I want to do.

Comment: jQuery does not support SVGs per se. In particular does jQuery not support case sensitive attribute names which SVGs do need. Otherwise yes, jQuery selector engine can traverse SVG nodes. When in doubt you need to use `.get` though to extract the DOM-Element from jQuery for Raphael to handle. A mapping over the element-Array might work better, but for more details you need to elaborate on your Markup and Code and all

Comment: @user3154108 I can't get it to work then, unfortunately. You would do something like: for-loop over the amount of `[parent='Norway']` elements, then `$("[parent='Norway']").get(i).toFront();` right? Where `i` is the current iteration. The problem is that it's not the DOM node that has the `toFront()` function, but it's the Raphael set element.

Comment: I would use Snap (Raphaels updated library) if possible, it's fairly compatible with Raphael and can use css selectors etc as desired.